# Does a central force have to be independent of angle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, symmetry, definition

When defining a central force, some sources, like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_force), say that the magnitude of the force only depends on the distance $r$:

> In classical mechanics, a **central force** on an object is a force whose magnitude only depends on the distance $r$ of the object from the origin and is directed along the line joining them:
>   $$\vec{F} = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}) = F(\lVert\mathbf{r}\rVert)\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$

While others, like [these lecture notes by Robert Hunt](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/ia-dyn-chapter6.pdf), only mention the direction which the force acts:

> A *central force* is one which is always directed towards or away from a fixed point, which we may take as our origin. In two dimensions, it is convenient to use plane polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$: then a central force $\mathbf{F}$ must be of the form $\mathbf{F} = f(r,\theta)\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r$.

Why the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Central force is derived from potential that depends only on $r$, i.e. $V(\vec{r})=V(r)$ and $\vec{F}=-\nabla V(r)$ . It follows that -

- Its magnitude dependts only on distance $r$
- Its direction is radial

Answer (score 0):

[The Wikipedia article you cite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_force) gives the key point at the end of the introduction:

> Equivalently, a force field is central if and only if it is spherically symmetric.

While there are various equivalent statements of a central force the one based on symmetry is probably the one most physicists would choose. For example, from the symmetry we immediately get conservation of angular momentum using Noether's theorem.

Comment: So is the symmetry definition equivalent to [this one](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/ia-dyn-chapter6.pdf) ?

Comment: @ConnorBishop: hmm, that article defines a central force as always directed towards a fixed point (i.e. the *centre*) and that is not the same as my or Alexander's definitions. As defined in that article the magnitude of the force can depend on angle as long as the direction is towards the centre. I think this is a minority definition of the term *central force* as most physicists would agree with Alexander and me. But then I'm not sure that a formal definition exists so I guess it comes down to how the term is most commonly used.